# How can I save the results the multiple files as a single file

Tags: r

I have many files with common column names. I am trying to save the results of these files in a single file after taking the means of each column. I am using append command but it save the each row with column names as well and that I don't want. I only want single column names not with every row. Any suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the files in using `read.csv`. It will work with plain text files as well as CSV files and offers the option of defining `header=TRUE`, which will read in the header line of a file as column names, rather than a row.

```
df1 <- read.csv("fileDir/input1.txt",sep=""),header=TRUE)
```

Then, when you have your files as dataframes, you can append them easily using `rbind`:

```
df_final <- rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```